# Turn off leds of Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, led

I would like to turn off the leds of my Raspberry Pi.

I tried modifying the file `echo none >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger` but nothing changed.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can disable the red power led, if thats what you mean? See here: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-disable-the-red-led-on-the-pi-camera-module/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### It's 2022, and the answer today is:

The documentation is located here, but it may or may not be up to date:

- on your *local* file system: `/boot/overlays/README`
- online at GitHub: [the README file](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README)

The README is a rather choppy document, but you can find enough to get started. The parameters of interest are `act_led_*`, and `pwr_led_*`. There are three device tree parameters (`dtparam`) for both `act_led` and `pwr_led`: `_trigger`, `_activelow` and `_gpio`, but the documentation doesn't mention all possible values for them. Through guesswork, I learned the following values will turn the *activity/green* and *power/red* LEDs OFF:

To turn both `act_led` and `pwr_led` OFF, add these two lines to the file `/boot/config.txt`, and then reboot:

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
```

#### However:

Changes made on Aug 8, 2022 to the Raspberry Pi's proprietary closed-source firmware have rendered the above configuration **ineffective on some models of RPi:**

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- Raspberry Pi 400
- Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4

For these models, with firmware versions issued since Aug. 8, 2022, the following configuration is needed to extinguish the Red Power LED (`pwr_led`):

```
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=default-on   # The default
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

There are also parameters for extinguishing the Ethernet LEDs also, but they only work for the 3B+ & 4B models:  `eth_led0` & `eth_led1`. Fortunately, the documentation does enumerate a set of values for the 3B+ and the 4B.

***UPDATE, 3/22/22:*** Additional details are now [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/LEDControlForRPi.md)

***UPDATE, 8/27/22:*** A recent software/firmware change by The RPi Organization seems to have broken the *device tree configuration* (`dtparam`) that disabled the Red Power LED. A [bug report was filed](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742) on 2022/08/21. I won't attempt to characterize the maintainer's responses; you may review them & draw your own conclusions.

As of now, I feel that the answer to the OP's question is that *`"it depends on the Raspberry Pi model"`*. I've edited my answer above based on the [*latest information*](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742#issuecomment-1229053776), but this saga will likely have more episodes! FWIW, the `sysfs` interface - deprecated ~ 2 years ago - still seems to be working if the correct file & value are used; the details are presented in [another Q&A on the same subject](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138783/83790).

***UPDATE, 12/27/22:***

Any further updates to this answer will be posted to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae).

Comment: Thank you for this answer Seamus! Countless other places online only repeat methods that no longer works for my case. But setting

dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=default-on   # The default
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off

In my /boot/config.txt and rebooting worked  (raspberry pi 4b)

Comment: @kschnack: Glad to hear it helped. Feel free to upvote :)

Comment: Well of course! Done ;)

Comment: For the Raspberry Pi 400 you can use `/sys/class/leds/PWR/brightness` (under Raspbian 11 Bullseye).

Answer (score 27):

```
RaspberryMediaCenter:/sys/class/leds # echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
RaspberryMediaCenter:/sys/class/leds # echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```

`led0` green one

`led1` red one

Answer (score 25):

According to the RaspberryPi forums:

```
echo 1 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness #Turn on
echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness #Turn off
```

Though I think some kernel hacking may be involved to control all of them, I believe this only works with the OK LED.

Comment: yes, I just checked, this does not turn off all LEDs. poo

Comment: Pi 3B+. This didn't affect the disk activity light (red aka led1) in the other answer that did work by Salvo Neutron.

Answer (score 6):

On the Pi you can control the 2 Leds (red and green) by editing the files located under:

```
/sys/class/leds/led[num]
```

For example to turn off the usual blinking of the green led when the Pi is accessing the sd card, you can run (as admin):

```
echo none > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

And to turn on or off one led, you can change the status of the brightness file (as admin):

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness     # turn on
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness     # turn off
```

This is my very inelegant workaround in Python to actually control the status:

```
import time
import os

# turn off the default trigger of the green LED
os.system("sudo bash -c \"echo none > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger\"")

# turn on the green LED
os.system("sudo bash -c \"echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness\"")

# keep it on 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

# turn off the green LED on PI
os.system("sudo bash -c \"echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness\"")
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which LED you are talking about, it looks like it is not possible.

For more information, read [How can I turn the lights off on my pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/how-can-i-turn-the-lights-off-on-my-pi) (and that's also a good place to ask RPi questions)

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is an old question. But, it was the first in the Google results for me, and it didn't work for my Raspberry Pi2 B+. For anyone else like me finding this now, the techniques at http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/controlling-pwr-act-leds-raspberry-pi did work.